# using Change Tracking functions from another database

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

If I turn on change tracking on a database called Production, can I use the functions to get the change data from another database?

For example: `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();`

I have tried the following, and also tried replacing the schema with `sys` but I don't think this approach is working:

```
Use [Analysis]
GO
SELECT Production.dbo.CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
```

I have worked around it by creating a stored procedure on Production that calls this function. Then I can call that stored procedure from other databases on that SQL Server. But would like to know if there is a more direct way.

I am trying to migrate data from one system to another (over a period of a week or two, then shut down the old system). Change tracking is enabled on the other database. I am limited by the version of SQL Server, CDC requires Enterprise, Developer or Evaluation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933945(v=sql.110).aspx) is a built in function not a UDF so `Production.dbo.CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()` isn't allowed.

It accepts no parameters to specify the database.

I would imagine that either of the following would work.

The first calls `Production.sys.sp_executesql` and executes the function. The second calls `sys.sp_executesql` in the current database and adds an explicit `USE` statement to set the context. I haven't set up change tracking and tested explicitly but both approaches work as desired with `DB_NAME()`

```
DECLARE @CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION BIGINT;

EXEC Production.sys.sp_executesql
  N'SELECT @ReturnValue = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()',
  N'@ReturnValue BIGINT OUTPUT',
  @ReturnValue = @CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION OUTPUT

SELECT @CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION
```

---

```
DECLARE @CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION BIGINT;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql
  N'USE Production;
    SELECT @ReturnValue = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()',
  N'@ReturnValue BIGINT OUTPUT',
  @ReturnValue = @CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION OUTPUT

SELECT @CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION
```